# Fetching recent/historical queries run on a database from an application

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c, oracle-sql-developer

I'm getting some database errors from an application related to unique constraints however none of the records have any duplicate values so I want to check what query was run that produced the error.

How can I check a history log of queries to pinpoint the problem? I'm using Oracle 12c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing enabled by default in the database. `V$` or `DBA_HIST` views are not guaranteed to contain all your SQL statements all the time. The amount of memory to store SQL statements in `V$` views is limited, and `DBA_HIST` views contain only sampled data. Furthermore, they do not store information about constraint violation errors.

If you want to find the SQLs causing unique constraint violation errors, you can create a trigger that catches the errors and logs information, for example:

```
create table userLog
(error_date date,
 username varchar2(30),
 error_msg clob,
 error_sql clob);

create or replace trigger log_errors after servererror on database
declare
   sql_text ora_name_list_t;
   msg clob := null;
   stmt clob := null;
   errnum number;
begin

   errnum := ORA_SERVER_ERROR(1);

   if (errnum = 1) then
       for i in 1 .. ora_server_error_depth loop
          msg := msg||ora_server_error_msg(i);
       end loop;
       for i in 1..ora_sql_txt(sql_text) loop
          stmt := stmt||sql_text(i);
       end loop;
       insert into userLog(error_date,username,error_msg,error_sql)values (sysdate,ora_login_user,msg,stmt);
   end if;
end;
/
```

The above trigger catches number `1` errors (that is for `ORA-00001: unique constraint () violated`) on the top of the stack (that is `ORA_SERVER_ERROR(1)`) in the database, and logs them in the `userlog` table with the SQL text, so you can find later the SQL statements that caused them.

Answer (score 0):

The data you require is exposed by the view `v$sql`.

You can narrow down the statement you're looking for by filtering on the `SQL_TEXT` column.

[Documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/REFRN/refrn30246.htm#REFRN30246).

If you have a diagnostics pack license, you can use the `DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT` view - it keeps snapshots of SQL statements that may have aged out of `v$sql`.